# What kind of tub spout do I need to buy?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, spout

I need to buy a new tub spout, but this is what the connector behind it is. Everything I see is either slip on or female thread on the spout itself. I am trying to find something that will work without tearing my wall apart. The piece on there seems to be glued on. [image]Thank you

Comment: What type was there before?

Comment: Look in the tub spout you removed for the "missing" pipe nipple...

Answer (score 2):

That should be CPVC with female 1/2 inch NPT.

Get a brass nipple in the same thread and length that will allow you to thread on a spout with female 1/2 NPT. Use a thread sealing paste not Teflon tape.

Polly or PVC is not rated for the hot water temps that can flow through the spout.